# iOSでローカル通知もしくはpush通知を行う際に祝日除外設定は可能でしょうか？

Tags: ios

iPhoneアプリで指定した間隔でユーザにお知らせするため、ローカル通知、push通知を使って通知を表示する実装を行っています。

例えば、「毎週月曜日の指定時刻」、「毎月第二、第四水曜日の指定時刻」に通知を表示するイメージです。

毎週月曜日に通知する場合でも、ハッピーマンデーなどで祝日の場合には通知を行いたくないのです。

Xcode7+Swift2で、試しにローカル通知で実装してみましたが、「repeatInterverl」で上に記述した指定は可能なようですが、祝日の通知除外を行う方法が分かりません。

(iOS標準ではない)目覚ましのアプリなどでは、祝日除外設定できるものがあるようですが、実現方法が分かりません。

どなたかご存じないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

祝日は国や（日本以外では）地方によっても異なり、毎年変わるので、非常に複雑ですので、iOSでは標準で祝日の機能は持っていません。

祝日の除外設定のあるアプリケーションは独自で祝日のデータを参照しています。
日本と一部の国だけに対応するだけであれば、それほど難しくはありません。

日本の祝日は、毎年法律で決定されるので、基本的には毎年データを更新する必要があります。
アプリケーションにデータを組み込んだ場合はアップデートが必要になります。

ネットワークアクセスが使えるなら、インターネット経由でデータを取得するようにしても良いでしょう。

上記の通り、祝日の定義は面倒なので、汎用のサービスは少ないですが、いくつかAPIにて取得できるサービスがあります。

http://calendar-service.net/api.php

Googleカレンダーの祝日カレンダーを利用するのも手だと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。  

祝日かどうかの判定を自前で行う必要は理解していたので、祝日計算、判定に関しては問題ありません。  
日本だけを考慮すれば良いので、自前で判定関数を実装しています。  

私が悩んでいたのは、例えばローカル通知を使う場合、NSLocalnotificationで取り扱うオブジェクト類に何らかのプロパティを設定する、もしくはイベントを拾ってプログラムを動作させることにより指定日を除外することが可能なのか？  

という点でした。  

恐らく、上述の実装は対応できない。ということですよね？  
果たして目覚ましアプリ系はどうやって実装しているのか？が気になりますが。。。  

となると、次案としては、自前でお知らせを表示する日付を判断して表示する仕組みが必要になります。

Comment: -案1、ローカル/push通知を行ったイベントを拾って、次の通知日を探して(探す際に次回通知日が祝日の場合には翌週にスキップする)通知する
　→AppDelegate内でdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions、didReceiveLocalNotificationの２つを試してみましたが、単に通知イベントが発生しただけではイベントを拾えず、「通知を見てユーザがアプリケーションを起動する」操作が発生しないと動作しないようでした。  
　　この場合、通知イベントが発生してもユーザがアプリを起動しない限り次の通知日を探索、設定できません。  

-案2、自前/既定の(Windowsのサービス、Linuxのデーモン)相当の仕組みを使い、常にバックグラウンドで監視して通知を行う
　→目覚ましアプリで祝日除外を行っているようなアプリケーションはこういった実装を行っているのでは無いか？と勝手に推測していますが、実装方法が分かりません。  

　果たしてどうしたらよいやら。。。  

-案3、→他にあるでしょうか？

再度、アドバイスいただけると助かります。

Comment: 質問の意図が分かりました。Local通知はあまり柔軟な運用はできないので、あらかじめ、Local通知の登録上限の範囲内で複数の通知を繰り返し設定することになります。（祝日の直前の週まで繰り返しで登録。次の週からは別の通知とするなど）
Push通知はサーバ側の実装でどうにでもできるので、柔軟にやりたい場合はPush通知をメインに実装するのが良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 返答が遅くなりました。

現状考えている仕様では、

- N人のユーザが5-10種類毎に指定時刻を登録し、各々のユーザ毎に通知する

仕様を想定しています。

push通知を使う場合、同一時刻にN人に一斉送信する同報機能として使う場合には便利な機能だと思いますが、前述の仕様を考慮すると目的には適さないと考えます。

となると対応案としては、

- 案1 ローカル/push通知を行ったイベントを拾って、次の通知日を探して(探す際に次回通知日が祝日の場合には翌週にスキップする)通知する
  - イベントのキャッチについては前述の通りです。
- 案2 自前/既定の(Windowsのサービス、Linuxのデーモン)相当の仕組みを使い、常にバックグラウンドで監視して通知を行う
  - iOSアプリは全く初めてなので、そもそもサービス的な機能を自前実装できるのか？という疑問も有ります。
- 案3 (提示いただいた案の)祝日直前の週まで繰返し、祝日をスキップして翌週は新たに登録
  - 通知対象の種類が増えるとMAX64個に抵触する可能性が高い

振り出しに戻ってしまいます。

次善の案は何かありますでしょうか？

Comment: 「MarkDownEditor」だと正しく表示されますが、MarkDown記法がきちんと描画されないのが気になりますが、記入の仕方がマズイのでしょうか？

Comment: @iosDevelopper やはりPush通知がベストですね。というかLocal通知では登録上限やiOSのバックグラウンド動作の制限により希望する動作は限定的でしか実現できません。Push通知は一斉通知のもの、とお考えのようですが、そんなことはありません。TwitterやFacebookの通知は一斉通知でしょうか？Push通知はむしろ、個々の端末を識別して送れるので、どれだけ個人にカスタマイズできるかという部分で真価を発揮します。案2についてですが、iOSはバックグラウンドでも動作に大きな制限がありますので、サービスのような動作はできません。例外的に、音楽やBLE、位置情報を使うアプリは長時間のバックグラウンド動作が認められていますが、目覚ましアプリでは無理です。（別の機能としてBLE、位置情報を使うようにするという手はあります。）案3はおっしゃる通り、上限に達しない範囲でなら良い方法だと思います。余談ですが、StackOverflowのコメント欄では箇条書きや改行は使えません。